# How mantain selected button in navigation bar using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am a beginner in angular js and have next problem : After login  show home page , which contains static sections  as header, navigation bar and footer but only a section in the center which change through behavior navigation bar.

I need  mantain state for navigation-bar when pressed button, actually in the file app.js inject views using  **ngRoute** module, and using **nginclude** for static section therefore loses state navigation bar when button pressed.

Comment: Im using [ng-view] for index.html and [ngroute] for application , but login page only contain form and home page contain header,nav-bar,footer in this view . The flow for login page to home page is perfect , but home page contain in the center differents views so im using [ng-include] in home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the `ngRoute` module ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)) and the `ng-view` directive ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView)) - that will most likely provide you with the routing mechanisms you need.

Take a look at documentation I point to - both pages contains complete examples of how to setup the router and use the `ng-view` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Hi my approach is to use [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive%3angView) directive, you can only have one in a page but that´s the prefect fit for you.

you can have your header / footer and for the content just use the ng-view, you will need to set up a [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) in your application to display a specific view/template controller for a configured path

Comment: Im using [ng-view] for index.html , but login page only contain form and home page contain header,nav-bar,footer in this view . The flow for login page to home page is perfect , but home page contain in the center differents views so im using [ng-include] in home page.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to do a full page redirect, from your login page to your internal homepage, as far I understood the design is quite different from one page to another so keeping differents "Index" files makes sense